# Why do first bitcoin transactions receive most confirmations?

Tags: transactions, bitcoin-core, confirmations

My very first Bitcoin transaction has 740 confirmations, the next have 239, 212, 70, 43, 5, and 5, respectively. Is this just because my first transaction has had more time to get more confirmations, or do first transactions always receive the most confirmations, even if the subsequent transactions follow immediately thereafter?

Viz., does the first bitcoin transaction need the most confirmations, such as to verify the legitimacy of a new user?

thanks

Comment: related: [What are bitcoin “confirmations”?](http://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/q/146/5406)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Once a transaction has one confirmation, it gets a confirmation whenever the network creates a new block (roughly every 10 minutes). If one of your transactions gets a confirmation, the rest will also get a confirmation if they have at least one confirmation already. So the difference in non-zero confirmations between your transactions will always remain the same (except in very rare cases when the block chain gets reorganized).

Going from 0 confirmations to 1 works differently.

https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Transactions
https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Blocks
https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Block_chain