# Pending transactions 0/3

Tags: blockchain

I sent bitcoin from my blockchain to my paxful and it says pending in my paxful history 0/3 confirm. Please what happened. And the bitcoin has left my blockchain wallet and it only showing unconfirmed in paxful history

Answer (score 1):

This means you have to wait until the transaction has [3 confirmations](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/146/what-are-bitcoin-confirmations) before you can use it on Paxful.  The time needed for each confirmation is random, but averages about 10 minutes.

By the time you read this, your transaction probably will have 3 confirmations.

If after several hours it still says 0/3, then go and read [Why is my transaction not getting confirmed and what can I do about it?](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/9046/why-is-my-transaction-not-getting-confirmed-and-what-can-i-do-about-it).  You may have set a transaction fee that was too low.

Answer (score 0):

It is due to lower fees. You can delete it (replace by fees) and make another with more fees. It will confirm.quickly.