# Can I confirm a transaction myself as a node?

Tags: mining-reward, full-node

I see notes that when I make a transaction, I can set the fee myself. But, if I set it too low, then the miners may decide not to take it because the fee is too low.

Can I make confirmation myself as a node or does it mean I will have to run a powerful machine and mine cryptocurrency in order to be able to select and confirm my own transactions?

Is it feasible to run my own node and process those transactions that I do myself?

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/q/146/5406

Answer (score 2):

By running a node, you verify that your transactions are actually valid and will be accepted by the network. However, to add it to a block, and hence the blockchain, you must solve the PoW challenge, as the difficulty is so high, you'll need some powerful machines and tons of electricity.

Answer (score 2):

Transactions are confirmed when miners include them in a block, which is then subsequently mined (by finding the right nonce - which is computationally hard). As you mentioned, they like to receive a fee for their services.

To answer your question: Unless you are able to mine the next block (e.g., by employing strong mining hardware), you can only broadcast and validate transactions. So while you may be able to create your own transactions, you ultimately rely on miners including them in blocks they mine.